# Can you clone an AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Cloning for different environments. Staging/QA/PROD/DEV etc.

Is there a quick an easy way to clone my lambdas, give a different name, and adjust configurations from there?

Comment: Use CloudFormation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to recreate your Lambda Functions in the new account. Go to lambda function click on Action and export your function .

> Download a deployment package (your code and libraries), and/or an AWS
>   Serverless Application Model (SAM) file that defines your function,
>   its events sources, and permissions.
>
> You or others who you share this file with can use AWS CloudFormation
>   to deploy and manage a similar serverless application. Learn more
>   about how to deploy a serverless application with AWS CloudFormation.

Comment: Note that the **prerequisite** for this answer is, you have to have and use AWS CloudFormation to deploy the exported serverless application.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of terraform code(Infrastructure as Code) which can be used to stamp out same lambdas within different environment dev/prod.
If you have a look at this bit of code `function_name = "${var.environment}-first_lambda"` it will be clear as to how the name of the function is prefixed with environments like dev/prod etc.
This variable can be passed in at terraform command execution time eg `TF_VAR_environment="dev" terraform apply` or defaulted in the variables.tf or passed in using *.tfvars

```
#main.tf 
resource "aws_lambda_function" "first_lambda" {
  function_name = "${var.environment}-first_lambda"

  filename         = "${data.archive_file.first_zip.output_path}"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.first_zip.output_base64sha256}"

  role    = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler = "first_lambda.lambda_handler"
  runtime = "python3.6"
  timeout = 15

  environment {
    variables = {
      value_one   = "some value_one"
    }
  }
}
# variables.tf
variable "environment" {
  type = "string"
  description = "The name of the environment within the project"
  default = "dev"
}
```

Comment: Ill mark this as the answer but I was basically able to do something very similar using https://serverless.com/ which allowed me to recreate the functions on demand.

Comment: Neither Terraform or Serverless are in-house solutions provided by AWS.

They are both 3rd party projects.