# How to make same lambda function name in different stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to use different stack to manage different environments `staging` and `prod`. But what I found is I can't deploy lambda function with same name to different stack. Do I have to give different name for different stack? If so, I have to create two `template.yaml` file for two envs. Is there a way to use one template file to manage multiple envs?

I am using `AWS SAM` to deploy my lambda. And I know I can setup different stack via the cli: `sam deploy --template-file mytemplate.yml --stack-name YOUR_ENVIRONMENT`. but how can I update the lambda function name via command line?

Comment: How about adding environment name for the function also? Like `!Sub ${project}-${environment}-function`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55941530/can-you-clone-an-aws-lambda/55942827#55942827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vahdet's comment is the right answer for your question. You should split your functions into different environments so you can prepend the environment's name to your functions.

So let's say you have a function called `image-thumbnail` but you want to deploy it to both staging and prod, so your function's name should be `staging-image-thumbnail` and `prod-image-thumbnail` respectively.

You did not mention nor tagged any framework you may be using, but if you're using either [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) or the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/), this feature is already built-in. If you're not using a framework, I highly suggest you start doing so as it will make your life way easier, especially when it comes to CI/CD pipelines.

In SAM, you could simply run:

`sam deploy --template-file mytemplate.yml --stack-name YOUR_ENVIRONMENT`

In the Serverless Framework, you could run:

`serverless deploy --stage YOUR_ENVIRONMENT`

Both these frameworks use `CloudFormation` under the hood, so essentially what they will do is create different stacks for different environments (with the name of the environment being part as the name of the stack), therefore guaranteeing unique both stack and function names.